# Qt QSqlQuery CREATE DATABASE

Tags: c++, mysql, база-данных, qt, mariadb

Пишу приложение под восьмеркой. Использую MariaDB. Через HeidiSQL(клиент к MySQL) создал базу данных. В своем приложении успешно подключаюсь к ней, успешно создаю таблицы и работаю с ними. Хочу из своего приложения создавать базу данных. Пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом, но query запрос всегда возвращает false и выводит в дебаг
"MySQL error: "
 
"MySQL error code:-1"
Как это нужно делать?

```
QSqlDatabase db_test = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db_test.setPort(3306);
db_test.setHostName("127.0.0.2");
db_test.setUserName("root");
db_test.setPassword("admin");

QSqlQuery query(db_test);

query.prepare( "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testDb");

if(query.exec()){
   qDebug()<<"It's OK";
}
else{
   qDebug()<<"MySQL error:" + query.lastError().text();
   qDebug()<<"MySQL error code:"+ QString::number(query.lastError().number());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, получается и без db.setDatabaseName("mysql")

Пробовал вот такой код:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
  DB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
  DB.setHostName("192.168.1.18");
  DB.setUserName("root");
  DB.setPassword("gfhjkm1");
  if(DB.open()) {
    QSqlQuery Query(DB);
    if (Query.exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS blablabla"))
      qDebug() << "Ok"; else qDebug() << "Error query";
  } else qDebug() << "Error open";
}
```

Для теста запустил тут:

- FreeBSD 11.0
- MySQL 5.6.33
- Qt 5.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте prepare. Используйте exec, как [тут](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23407-problem-creating-a-mysql-database?s=3f1382582e71b8140c935bca99e88f26&p=150026#post150026)

```
void MainWindow::creadb()
{
QString db_conti = "conti1";

QSqlDatabase db =      QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("mysql");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword(ui->password->text());
if (db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("create database "+db_conti);

    qWarning()<<query.lastError();

... code for creating tables, views and users...

    db.close();

}

}
```